# System.OutOfMemoryException while MDX Query using Invoke-ASCmd

Tags: powershell, out-of-memory, ssas, ascmd

i want to import a MDX result set into Powershell using Invoke-ASCmd.

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
Import-Module SQLASCMDLETS

Push-Location SQLSERVER:\SQLAS\$ServerInstance\Default\Databases\$Database\Cubes\

$result = Invoke-ASCmd -Database $Database -Query $Query

Pop-Location
```

It fails with a `System.OutOfMemoryException`

- The same MDX query works fine in SQL Server Management Studio.
- There is still a lot of RAM free.
- The Powershell runs in 64bit mode.
- MaxMemoryPerShellMB is increased.
- I am using SQL Server 2016 and Powershell 4

What's to do, to import large datasets from SQL Server Analysis Services using Powershell?

Comment: What software versions are involved? How large is the result set?

Comment: google for System.OutOfMemoryException, it's not necessarily about the RAM. Can you post entire script you are running?

Comment: I fixed the example. The Parameters are Database, ServerInstance (Hostname) and Query.

Answer (score 1):

I found an workaround for this:

If you add a linked server to a SQL Server to the SSAS Cube you can execute it wrapped in SQL.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd `
    -ServerInstance $ServerInstance `
    -Query "SELECT * FROM OpenQuery([SSAS_LinkedServer],'$( $query.Replace("'", "''" ) )')"
```